# Get mysql error when deploy laravel project with Docker

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

I want to test my laravel project with the same inviroment like remote server. So i try to use Docker (never know before). I installed docker, and follow the instruction in project to deploy it with docker. 
Setup

Copy file .env.example to .env, docker-compose.yml.example to docker-compose.yml

Modify .env config file (optional). If you modify the mysql, mongo, redis configurations in .env file, remember to modify the configurations in docker-compose.yml file too.
Install or run Docker

```
docker-compose up -d
```

// Stop

```
docker-compose stop
```

chmod cache folders

```
chmod -R 777 storage

chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
```

Deploy

```
sh deploy.sh
```

After running `sh doploy.sh` i got this error:

```
   [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                              
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = awesome_teacher and table_name = migrations)
 [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                              
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables w  
  here table_schema = homestead_test and table_name = migrations)                                                               
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
[PDOException]                                    
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

File "docker-compose.yml":

```
version: '2'

### Change the `teacher` with your own teacher name ###
services:
    application:
        container_name: teacher_application
        image: debian
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/laravel
    workspace:
        container_name: teacher_workspace
        restart: always
        image: my_company/laravel-workspace
        volumes_from:
            - application
        tty: true
    php-fpm:
        container_name: teacher_php-fpm
        restart: always
        image: my_company/laravel-php-fpm
        volumes_from:
            - application
        expose:
            - "9000"
        links:
            - workspace
    nginx:
        container_name: teacher_nginx
        restart: always
        image: my_company/laravel-nginx
        volumes_from:
            - data
            - logs
            - application
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        links:
            - php-fpm
    data:
        container_name: teacher_data
        image: debian
        volumes:
            - .docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
            - .docker/data:/data
    data_test:
        container_name: teacher_data_test
        image: debian
        volumes:
            - .docker/mysql_test:/var/lib/mysql
            - .docker/data_test:/data
    logs:
        container_name: teacher_logs
        image: debian
        volumes:
            - .docker/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
            - .docker/logs/mongodb:/var/log/mongodb
    mysql:
        container_name: teacher_mysql
        restart: always
        image: mysql
        volumes_from:
            - data
            - logs
        expose:
            - "3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: awesome_teacher
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: blablabla
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: blablabla
    mysql_test:
        container_name: teacher_mysql_test
        restart: always
        image: mysql
        volumes_from:
            - data_test
        expose:
            - "3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead_test
            MYSQL_USER: homestead_test
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

File ".env":

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:hl4qkfCdHiJrCG4sGfYfMU8faq3WywMHkH+mr/FiDu9PM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=awesome-teacher.local
APP_DOMAIN='awesome-teacher.local'


DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=awesome_teacher
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=blablabla

DB_TEST_CONNECTION=mysql_test
DB_TEST_HOST=localhost
DB_TEST_PORT=3308
DB_TEST_DATABASE=homestead_test
DB_TEST_USERNAME=homestead_test
DB_TEST_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=
```

Comment: DB_HOST should be your MySQL service name which is ```mysql```
and not ```localhost```

Comment: I found the answer, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a complex setup for a simple laravel application. The problem is that your laravel app tries to connect to a `MySQL` server instance in its own container.

Change `DB_HOST=localhost` to `DB_HOST=mysql` to connect to the `mysql` container instead.